# How to use functions inside ngClass?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use functions with ngClass to separate logic from my template to make the code more maintainable, but am getting all options highlighting red initially from the is-incorrect style. Please see my code below:

```
<mat-radio-button class="answer" [value]="option.optionValue" disableRipple="true"
[ngClass]="{'initial-state': initialState(),
            'is-correct': isCorrect(),
            'is-incorrect': isIncorrect()}">
</mat-radio-button>

initialState(): boolean {
  return this.selectedRadioButtonOption === '';
}

isCorrect(): boolean {
  return this.option === this.question.correctAnswer
           && this.selectedRadioButtonOption === this.question.correctAnswer;
}

isIncorrect(): boolean {
  return this.option !== this.question.correctAnswer
           && this.selectedRadioButtonOption === this.option;
}
```

Comment: maybe is because u dont import a provider for your mat-radio-button. show the highlight comment.

Comment: I'm using provider in my app.module.ts file: providers: [{
    provide: MAT_RADIO_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
    useValue: { color: 'accent' },
  }],

Comment: you have this in any module? import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';

Comment: Are you using an ngFor loop to create the radio buttons?

Comment: i have import { MatRadioModule, MAT_RADIO_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/radio'; in my app.module.ts file

Comment: yes I'm using ngFor for the radio buttons.

Comment: So "option" is the variable in the loop but you also use this.option in the ts file. So is "option" a seperate variable in the ts file?

Comment: yes I have set option = ''; in the ts file. And also selectedRadioButtonOption = '';

Comment: why NOT use [(ngModel)] o ReactiveForms? else you need use (change) to change the valur of the option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment you said you are creating the radio buttons in a ngFor loop. So in the HTML, "option", is referring to the data of a specific radio button. In the TS file "option" is its own varaible so it would never change. Try sending the option value into the functions.

So it would look like this

```
<mat-radio-button class="answer" [value]="option.optionValue" disableRipple="true"
[ngClass]="{'initial-state': initialState(),
        'is-correct': isCorrect(option.optionValue),
        'is-incorrect': isIncorrect(option.optionValue)}">
</mat-radio-button>

initialState(): boolean {
  return this.selectedRadioButtonOption === '';
}

isCorrect(option): boolean {
  return option === this.question.correctAnswer
       && this.selectedRadioButtonOption === option;
}

isIncorrect(option): boolean {
  return option !== this.question.correctAnswer
       && this.selectedRadioButtonOption === option;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I made those changes but still am getting all red highlighted options. Is it because I have declared both option and selectedRadioButtonOption to '' ?

Comment: You will also need to change the other "this.option" to "option" in the functions. Sorry I missed those the first time. I updated the anwser

Comment: Tried changing this.option to option and the buttons have turned gray initially but don't change to green or red when I am clicking on them\

Comment: You will need to have a click event setup that will change the selectedRadioButtonOption variable to the option that is clicked

Comment: yes I think I had one before but removed it...(click)="selectedRadioButtonOption = option.optionValue"

Comment: It should be just option. So try... selectedRadioButtonOption = option. Let me know if that works

Comment: Still not working. Please could you take a look at my StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qykleb

Comment: Okay, I see now. I updated the awnser. Change the parameter in the function calls to option.optionValue and remove the click event. This will work but this setup will run into issue when you go to another question.

Comment: Thanks, changing to option.optionValue worked! What should I do for the other questions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200081/discussion-between-william-stevens-and-multiv123).